# How to download our app from iTunes connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Is there a way to download our exact Xcode file that represents are app on the App Store. I have lost one of my files for my app but its on the App Store. If there is a way to download the exact file that would be very helpfulll. I have heard of the dSYM file but do not know what it is. Any links to any tutorials would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Simply recover the missing file from your source code control (such as git) or from Time Machine or the backup your made of your project. Sure you use at least two of those, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible due to the app being compiled and packaged into an iOS app store package (IPA).

Comment: Thanks for response what is a dSYM FILE?

Comment: a dsym file contains all the symbols (function names and other debug info) used for debugging your application. @sillymilly

Comment: So are you saying that I can get the whole string of the code I coded? Like all of the View Controllers.

Comment: No, it mainly just contains the names and lines, making it quite impossible to recover your source through it. It is mainly used for decoding crash logs and debugging. @sillymilly